# Adding images in HTML

Tags: html

I have been trying to add an image for the past 2 days, I watched some feeds here, I have watched some videos on Youtube aswell and I have searched it on google, but it does not work. I have saved different images in the desktop and added in the visual studio code template where the index file is, but it does not work at all, it displays the alt attribute text, but it does not display the photo. Can somebody please tell me what is the issue? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src = "Trulli.jpg" width = 100 height = 100>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share a ss of your file explorer?

Comment: Is your image in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: Not one day goes by without this same question that will result in the same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always upload your image using a provider like https://imgbb.com/
and then linking it to your project.

`<img src="https://www.example.url/sadasd width = "1920" height = "1080" />`

Or you can Maybe add the image into your parent directory and add the image src.

`<img src="./Trulli.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>`

Using frameworks such as React, Vue and others allows ease of use while importing images into the `/Public` folder created.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thank you, I will use these methods and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you, I have used the imgbb for doing this, thank you infinetely

Answer (score 0):

The image you are trying to add should be in the same folder or place your code file is or you have to give full path info while calling img src="path"

[Screenshot of the File and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvyM7.png)

Comment: I tried I went to the visual studio code and right clocked on the image and clicked on copy relative path, then I pasted and runned, but it is still not working. Thank you.

Comment: your code works I tried it myself. just make sure you have the correct path for the image. Just to try make sure, create a new folder and keep both .html file and .jpg in same folder and and open the html file like i did in the pic.